# ¿Cómo hacer una aplicación Java con una base de datos interna?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas, mi problema es que no tengo muy claro cómo hacer la base de datos de mi aplicación en Java. Lo que quiero es hacer un instalador de mi aplicación y que la información se obtenga de una base de datos, pero no sé donde se ejecutaría la base de datos si no quiero tener un servidor externo. Gracias de antemano

Comment: La pregunta tal vez es muy amplia, los datos que vas a manejar los necesitas controlar tú o sólo el usuario, por ejemplo imaginemos una aplicación de tareas 'en local', es decir sólo se almacenarán los datos en el dispositivo que estés utilizando no en cualquier dispositivo que se conecte a tu aplicación. Si es así, puedes optar por bases de datos locales o incluso ficheros, si no es así base de datos remota (externa) y con ella trabajarías a través de peticiones HTTP.

Comment: Puedes usar sqlite. mira esta guia: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm

Comment: Gracias por responder. Sí, en este caso sería que solo el usuario necesita controle los datos. Voy a leer sobre SQlite gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso puedes usar una base de datos embebida.

### ¿Qué es una base de datos embebida?

Se trata de bases de datos que carecen de servidor, están cómo su nombre lo dice **embebidas** en la propia aplicación y suelen estar almacenadas en ficheros locales.

### Opciones que puedes utilizar:

- Apache Derby
- SQLite
- ObjectDBC

Comment: Cómo sugerencia yo he usado apache derby y me parece muy bueno, aparte de que sí usas NetBeans este tiene opciones que te permiten crear todo lo necesario para realizar la conexión, manipular y visualizar los datos.
Te dejaré algunos enlaces que podrían ayudarte si es que decides usar derby:
https://aflrovvs.blogspot.mx/2012/06/conexion-de-java-y-derby-utilizando.html
http://wiki.netbeans.org/GetStartedwithJavaDB
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

Comment: Una pregunta: Podría hacer la base de datos usando Workbench y exportar para sqlite?